# Best way to dynamically change class variables

Tags: python, class, methods

I want to dynamically change class variables in a method. What's the best way to do that? I don't know the best practice for it. Currently I get the error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'` as python doesn't recognize my changed str as an object.

`self.LE_Donald_name` is a button in Qt that has already been created so it's an existing object of my class and there is for example also a button that is called `self.LE_Matthew_name` I would like to call in some cases.

I'm trying to dynamically call existing objects of my class.

**I run the method:**

```
self.filter_contact_entry_widget("Donald")
```

**Which calls my class method.**

```
def filter_contact_entry_widget(self, occGroup):
        sample_entry = "LE_" + occGroup + "_name"
        main_contact = "LE_" + occGroup + "main_contact"
        stand_in_contact = "LE_" + occGroup + "stand_in_contact"

        search_results = self.sApp.search_contact_by_company(self.sample_dicts, self.sample_entry.text())
```

**I made a simplified version of my problem to clarify my issue:**

```
class MyClass:
    def __ini__(self):
        self.LE_donald_name = "Donald Duck"
        self.LE_mickey_name = "Mickey Mouse"

    def call_firstname(self, firstName):
        sample_entry = "LE_" + firstName + "_name"
        self.my_print(self.sample_entry)

    def my_print(self, userInput):
        print(userInput)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyClass().call_firstname("donald")
```

Comment: In most cases you should use a dictionary and the "variable" names as keys instead of adding attributes dynamically. If you really want to, look at functions "setattr" and "getattr".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at what's happening in the first line.

```py
sample_entry = "LE_" + occGroup + "_name"
```

This creates a local variable, `sample_entry`, which is a string that is something like `"LE_Donald_name"`.

BUT you don't want that string, you want the attribute called `"LE_Donald_name"` that belongs to the object, i.e., `self.LE_Donald_name`. You cannot access `self.LE_Donald_name` via `self.sample_entry` even though you have a local variable called `sample_entry` that contains `"LE_Donald_name"`. Instead, use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) (this is exactly why this built-in function exists).

```py
def filter_contact_entry_widget(self, occGroup):
    sample_entry = "LE_" + occGroup + "_name"
    # ...
    button = getattr(self, sample_entry)  # Get, e.g., self.LE_Donald_name.
    search_results = self.sApp.search_contact_by_company(self.sample_dicts, button.text())
```

To confirm that you're getting what you want, you might try something like `print(type(button))`.

Comment: @valPelt2 So took me a short amount of time to set it up. But now there's a simplified example of my error in the question :)

Comment: Seems like I've never had to use `getattr()` bevor so thank you for your input that fixes my problem!